# Fetch Data from ForeignKey Relationahip in Django - Filtering

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models:

```
class Card(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    mentioner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='Mentioner')

class Profile(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    card_mention = models.ForeignKey(Card, related_name='Mentionee')
```

When a user creates a card, he or she can "mention" another user in this card (as the mentioner). He or she can actually mention zero users, him or herself, and any number of other users (or profiles actually, since users and profiles are linked).

If I pass the data into the context for a template, how would I set this up in a view, for example, such that I can get get the mentioned profiles from the card?

In other words, in a template, lets say I'm building a feed of these cards with mentions in them. I want to list all mentioned profiles in the card (in the template). How would I fetch these profiles for this purpose?

I'm stuck with using some kind of filter maybe. I can fetch all the profile objects, but then I need a way to filter based on which profiles are associated with each card according to the above relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider rewriting your model so you are using a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) as it closer models your idea, being:

- Cards have one author (Profile)
- Cards can mention zero or more mentions of other users (Profile)

So your code would be:

```
class Card(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='cards_authored')
    mentions = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='cards_mentioned_in')

class Profile(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This means in a view you are then able to show all the mentions for the current user:

```
def show_users_mentions(request):
    user = request.user
    mentions = Card.objects.filter(mentions=user)
    # do something with mentions
```

Or get all of the users mentioned on a particular card:

```
def show_mentions_on_card(request,card_id):
    card = Card.objects.get(pk=card_id)
    mentions = card.mentions
    # do something with mentions
```